# Creating network device

Tags: c++, c, winapi, device-driver

here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winerror.h>
#include <Winbase.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <Setupapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef BOOL WINAPI (*InstallSelectedDriverProto)(HWND, HDEVINFO, LPCTSTR, BOOL, PDWORD);

int main()
{
  InstallSelectedDriverProto InstallSelectedDriver;

  static const int MAX_NAME = 256;

  HDEVINFO devs = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

  char infPath[260] = {0};

  char deviceId[260] = {0};

  DWORD reboot = 0;

  HMODULE newDll = NULL;

  int devNameSize = 260;

  GUID classGUID = {0};

  char ClassName[MAX_NAME] = {0};

  char hwIdList[LINE_LEN + 4] = {0};

  SP_DEVINFO_DATA deviceData = {0};

  SP_DRVINFO_DATA driverInfoData = {sizeof(SP_DRVINFO_DATA)};

  const char *hwid;

  char *devName = NULL;

  hwid = "net";

  char *inf;

  inf = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Infs\\net.inf";

  strncpy(infPath, inf, sizeof(infPath)-1);

  infPath[sizeof(infPath)-1] = '\0';

  memset(hwIdList, 0, sizeof(hwIdList));

  strcpy(hwIdList, hwid);

  if (SetupDiGetINFClass(infPath, &classGUID,
                              ClassName, MAX_NAME, 0) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiGetINFClass failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  devs = SetupDiCreateDeviceInfoList(&classGUID, 0);

  if (devs == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
  {
    printf("devs == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  deviceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

  if (devName == NULL || devName[0] == 0)
  {
    if (SetupDiCreateDeviceInfo(devs, hwid, &classGUID, NULL, 0,
                                     DICD_GENERATE_ID, &deviceData) == FALSE)
    {
      printf("SetupDiCreateDeviceInfo failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
      fflush(stdout);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    strcpy(deviceId, "Root\\");

    strcat(deviceId, ClassName);
    strcat(deviceId, "\\");
    strcat(deviceId, devName);

    if (SetupDiCreateDeviceInfo(devs, deviceId, &classGUID,
                                     NULL, 0, 0, &deviceData) == FALSE)
    {
      printf("SetupDiCreateDeviceInfo failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
      fflush(stdout);
    }
  }

  if (SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty(devs, &deviceData,
                                            SPDRP_HARDWAREID, (BYTE *) hwIdList,
                                                (strlen(hwIdList) + 2)) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiSetDeviceRegistryProperty failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
  }


  if (SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_REGISTERDEVICE,
                                     devs, &deviceData) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiCallClassInstaller failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  newDll = LoadLibrary("newdesv.dll");

  if (newDll == NULL)
  {
    printf("newDll == NULL.\n");
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  InstallSelectedDriver = (InstallSelectedDriverProto) GetProcAddress(newDll, "InstallSelectedDriver");

  if (InstallSelectedDriver == NULL)
  {
    printf("InstallSelectedDriver == NULL failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  if (SetupDiSetSelectedDevice(devs, &deviceData) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiSetSelectedDevice failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
  }


  if (SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList(devs, &deviceData,
                                        SPDIT_COMPATDRIVER) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
  }


  if (SetupDiCallClassInstaller(DIF_SELECTBESTCOMPATDRV, devs,
                                       &deviceData) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiBuildDriverInfoList failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  if (SetupDiGetSelectedDriver(devs, &deviceData,
                                      &deviceData) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("SetupDiGetSelectedDriver failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
  }

  if (InstallSelectedDriver(NULL, devs, NULL, TRUE, &reboot) == FALSE)
  {
    printf("InstallSelectedDriver failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
    fflush(stdout);
  }


  if (devName && devNameSize > 0)
  {
    if (SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(devs, &deviceData,
                                      devName, devNameSize, NULL) == FALSE)
    {
      printf("SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
      fflush(stdout);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is create a network device. I'm having `Segmentation fault` but don't know why. I can't paste the whole `.inf` file because it's University project but,  it clearly has

```
[Version]
Signature = "$Windows NT$"
Class = Net
ClassGUID = {4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
```

I tried different things and noticed that `SetupDiCreateDeviceInfo` may be the problem, because I tried to delete the command and everything below it, and in that case everything works fine. Sorry if question is silly, I'm new with winapi. Thanks.

**P.S**
About the problem with `SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId`, As I meantion in comments it gives me `Segmentation fault`, I even tried this version:

```
char *devName1 = NULL;
if (SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(devs, &deviceData,
                                  devName1, devNameSize, NULL) == FALSE)
{
  printf("SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId failed. %d\n", GetLastError());
  fflush(stdout);
}
```

Created separated variable and initialized, but it gives me same error.

Comment: `devName` is uninitialized.

Comment: Thank you so much! how could I be so stupid.

Comment: One more question please sometimes The `wait operation timed out`(winapi error code 258) is returned from `InstallSelectedDriver` any idea why?

Comment: and `SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(devs, &deviceData,
                                      devName, devNameSize, NULL` gives seg fault too

Comment: There are no *"Segmentation faults"* in Windows. Please exercise more diligence in describing your problem.

Comment: I'm using cygwin, and console it gives me that.

Comment: For future reference, that's something you should have mentioned in the original question.  Cygwin applications aren't the same as normal Windows applications, so something that works fine under Windows might not work under Cygwin and vice-versa.

Comment: As for the problem with `SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId`, you'll need to post the updated code.  The most likely cause is a problem with the output buffer, which is the same `devName` that isn't initialized in the posted code.

Comment: sorry for late response, I've edited the code, thanks for helping me :)

Comment: You have to provide a buffer for the data, you can't just pass a null pointer.  (Well, technically you *can* provide a null pointer - either `DeviceInstanceId` or `RequiredSize` can be null, but not both.  What use would there be in calling the function and not receiving any data back?)

Comment: thank you so much for everything ! :) post it as answer and I'll approve it

Comment: and I would feel happy, it you suggested anything on this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789776/winapi-could-not-found-the-device-id-in-reg-keys